# Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection

Tags: mysql, nodejs, base-de-datos, express

¿Alguna idea de como puedo solucionar este error?

> Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection:
> connectionId. This is currently a warning, but in future versions of
> MySQL2, an error will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration
> option to a Connection

Estoy tratando de hacer consultas desde postman a la base de datos, la conexión está bien, las rutas aparentemente también, probé a hacer otro proyecto prueba con otra base de datos mysql pero el error persiste y no se me ocurre donde puede estar el problema.

Comment: El problema está en  la conexión. Como el mensaje te lo dice, no te va a evitar que te conectes, pero en versiones más nuevas si. En los datos de conexión hay algún parametro de más que estas pasando y que  no debe de ir, ó puede que esté mal escrito, pero sin la trasa completa del error ni la estructura para la conexión es dificil ayudarte.